# Finite Borel measures that don't agree on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

How would I go about finding a family $X$ of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$ that generate the Borel $\sigma$-algbera on $\mathbb{R}$ and two finite Borel measure $\mu$ and $\nu$ that agree on $X$ but do not agree on the whole Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that $X$ cannot be a $\Pi$-system, so I was thinking of using the open intervals but I'm really struggling with the measures. The only finite measures I can think of are Dirac point measures.

Comment: Take $X$ to be the open intervals not containing $0$, one measure the zero measure and the other the Dirac point measure at $0$.

Comment: I don't know if it may be helpful, but getting a finite measure is not so hard - in one way, you can use $\arctan$ to contract $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and measure contracted sets or you can use integrals to define the measure of a set. Any integrable and non-negative function is OK.

Comment: Now t.b. has an example where $X$ is a $\Pi$-system, but $\mu(\mathbb R) \ne \nu(\mathbb R)$.  How about another example where $X$ is not a $\Pi$-system and $\mu(\mathbb R) = \nu(\mathbb R)$ ??

Answer (score 2):

Is this question really 8 months old?  Try this:

Let $\mathcal X$ consist of all borel sets $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that 
$$
\text{either}\qquad
A \cap \{1,2,3,4\} = \{1,2\}\qquad\text{or}\qquad
A \cap \{1,2,3,4\} = \{1,3\} .
$$
Let $\mu = \delta_1+\delta_4$.  That is, points $1$ and $4$ each have measure $1$, everything else measure zero.  And let $\nu = \delta_2 + \delta_3$.

Show: (a) $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal X$. (b) $\sigma(\mathcal X)$ is all Borel sets.

Answer (score 0):

See  t.b.'s  another construction:  Take $X$ to be the open intervals of $R$ not containing 
$0$  and $1$, one measure Dirac point measure at $0$ and  the other the 
Dirac point measure at $1$. Both measures are nontrivial  and  agree on $X$.

Comment: A tricky one!  This $X$ does not generate the Borel sigma-algebra.  Any set in it either contains both $0,1$ or neither.